# python apscheduler.scheduler for add_date_job doesn't work

Tags: python, scheduled-tasks, apscheduler

I try something like this

```
import requests
from datetime import datetime
from apscheduler.scheduler import Scheduler



url = 'http://example.com?'
headers = {
    'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8',
}

data = {'simple'='good'}

def my_job():
    r = requests.post(url, data=data, headers=headers)
    print r.text
    print datetime.now()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    scheduler = Scheduler(standalone=True)

    job = scheduler.add_date_job(my_job, '2013-12-31 13:53:27.100000')
    print('Press Ctrl+C to exit')
    try:
        scheduler.start()
    except (KeyboardInterrupt, SystemExit):
        pass
```

My problem is that the trigger fires, but the print in req function doesn't show. It seems that requests cannot be sent. The request function is healthy because try it, but it did not work with Scheduler.

Comment: So what exactly is the problem? If the trigger works fine then there is no problem with the scheduler, right? Are you getting an error?